# Android zip files with password

Tags: android

I have done the portion to zip files programmatically using the available Zip class in Android.

But how do I zip with a password? I tried checking the developer website at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html

But there is no portion on password. Can it be done in Android?

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773097/how-to-create-a-normal-password-protected-zip-archive). The idea is to use a Java library that supports adding password which is compatible with android