# Is it possible to create a password-protected Zip file in android?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on my android app that can zip the selected files in a listview and later can be upload in google drive for backup purposes. one the objective of my app is to put a password in the zip file that will be created, so that only authorize person can open it.

Is it possible to create a password-protected Zip file in android? I read some questions here that is related to my question just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773097/how-to-create-a-normal-password-protected-zip-archive) and it really got me confused. please enlighten me guys. I'm kinda new in this Android development. so if it is possible can you give me an example of how to do this, or is there a simple ways on how to do this?

thank you in advance! I really appreciate it.

Comment: anybody solved this in kotlin ?.